# Check value is in array of objects in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function that is checking a value submitted by the user against a list of winning entries for a competition.

Currently if the user enters "1234" it's returning false, even though the value is there, but if a user enters "5678" it returns true and sends back all the data associated with that entry.

Can anybody point out why it's only finding the last value in the array true? I've tried a few different approaches, but nothing is working!

```
$entries = array(
  (object) [
    "uid" => "1234",
    "item" => "x",
    "text_prefix" => "x",
    "text_suffix" => "x",
    "prize_link" => "x",
    "data_captcher" => true
  ],
  (object) [
    "uid" => "5678",
    "item" => "x",
    "text_prefix" => "x",
    "text_suffix" => "x",
    "prize_link" => "x",
    "data_captcher" => false
    ],
);

// $data = json_encode($entries);
// echo $data;

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  $code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';

  var_dump($code);

  // foreach ($entries as $entry => $entry_Value) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($entries); $x++) {
    // var_dump($entry->uid);

    if ($entries[$x]->uid == $code) {
      $value = [
        "uid" => $entries[$x]->uid,
        "item" => $entries[$x]->item,
        "text_prefix" => $entries[$x]->text_prefix,
        "text_suffix" => $entries[$x]->text_suffix,
        "prize_link" => $entries[$x]->prize_link,
        "data_captcher" => $entries[$x]->data_captcher,
      ];
    }else {
      $value = 'false';
    }

    // var_dump($entries[$x]);
  }

  $data = json_encode($value);
  echo $data;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple, you miss a stop condition.
Your loop iterates all entries, so the last entry will determine whether `value` is false or not.

What you should do is add `break` in your `if` condition:

```
if ($entries[$x]->uid == $code) {
  $value = [
    "uid" => $entries[$x]->uid,
    "item" => $entries[$x]->item,
    "text_prefix" => $entries[$x]->text_prefix,
    "text_suffix" => $entries[$x]->text_suffix,
    "prize_link" => $entries[$x]->prize_link,
    "data_captcher" => $entries[$x]->data_captcher,
  ];

  break;  // <== this will stop the "for" loop
}else {
  $value = 'false';
}
```

By the way, in your case I would use `foreach` loop for readability reasons:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
   :
   :
}
```

Comment: Yeah a break was needed! I'n my head I thought i'd added one.... it's been a long day! Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are just not stopping when you find the match. And the next iteration is a non-match so you end up returning a false. You need to stop looping when you find a match, you can stop a loop with a `break;`

Also the `foreach` is a simpler loop than a `for`

Also you do not need to do all those assignments when you find the right object, just do a `$value = $entry_obj;` and its all done.

```
$entries = array(
    (object) [
      "uid" => "1234",
      "item" => "x",
      "text_prefix" => "x",
      "text_suffix" => "x",
      "prize_link" => "x",
      "data_captcher" => true
    ],
    (object) [
      "uid" => "5678",
      "item" => "x",
      "text_prefix" => "x",
      "text_suffix" => "x",
      "prize_link" => "x",
      "data_captcher" => false
      ],
);

$data = json_encode($entries);

$_POST['code'] = '1234';
$code = isset($_POST['code']) ? $_POST['code'] : '';
  
var_dump($code);
  
foreach ($entries as $entry_obj) {
    if ($entry_obj->uid == $code) {
        $value = $entry_obj;
        break;  // found it so stop otherwise we dont find it on next iteration
    }else {
        $value = 'false';
    }
}
  
$data = json_encode($value);
echo $data;
```

RESULT

```
{
    "uid":"1234",
    "item":"x",
    "text_prefix":"x",
    "text_suffix":"x",
    "prize_link":"x",
    "data_captcher":true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution you can use a combination of [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

```php
// First re-key the array so that uid is the key
$entries = array_column($entries, null, 'uid');

// Then you can check if the array key exists directly, and assign a default value if not
$value = $entries[$code] ?? 'false';
```